# Error Starting Docker Daemon on CentOS 7

Tags: docker, centos

Seems like I can't start the Docker service for the first time using `systemctl start docker`. I keep running into this exact error below:

`Error starting daemon: couldn't create plugin manager: error setting plugin manager root to private: permission denied`

My docker installation steps on my CentOS 7(64x) machine:

```
yum install -y yum-utils \
  device-mapper-persistent-data \
  lvm2

yum-config-manager \
    --add-repo \
    https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

yum install docker-ce

systemctl start docker
```

Yes, the provided commands were run as root.

Comment: What version of `docker-ce`? There are some similar reports over at https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34680.  That may be a better place to address your question.